# Strip Incomplete HTML Tags using PHP / HTMLPurifier

Tags: php, html-parsing, html-email, htmlpurifier

Given the following html:

```
<p>I am a paragraph</p>

<ul>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="special_div_from_email_client">
<span>Some text
```

I need to strip out the  tag that is not complete.

What we are trying to do is parse email messages by placing a custom string in the original message so that if it is included in the response it can be stripped out. The assumption is that if the email program enclosed the original message in any html tags, we want to remove the enclosing html tags.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be exactly what you're looking for, but I've found that removing invalid tags will sometimes break the rest of your HTML email (specifically `TR` and `TD` tags if you're using tables for layout).

It might be better to use one of these libraries/tools to complete/fix the HTML for you. You can then traverse the DOM in your valid HTML to remove/modify elements.

- http://de3.php.net/manual/en/intro.tidy.php
- http://htmlpurifier.org/
- http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

This might seem like a long way round, but I hope this helps.

Comment: We are using htmlpurifier. Our hope originally was that htmlpurifier would be capable of removing the broken elements but I can' find anything that shows how.

Comment: It's been a while since I did this but I think you need the PHP Tidy extension. [This is the method](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/tidy.cleanrepair.php) you'd need to repair broken HTML. Check out the example on that page.

Comment: That does the same thing that htmlpurifier already does by default. Given my original example, I actually want the broken <div> to be removed, not repaired. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't be more help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you put a string in the original. If that was placed before your original message body, couldn't you so do a strpos and substr to trim your email? here is a function I just threw together as an example:

```
// myKey can be a comment before the body of your message, $html is your email content
function trim($html, $myKey){
  $htmlTrimmed = $html;
  if (strpos($html, $myKey)!==false){
    $origStart = strpos($html, $myKey);
    $htmlTrimmed = substr($html, 0, $origStart);
  }
  return $htmlTrimmed;
}
```

I didn't test it, but you get the idea.